# SVG icons blur/unblur in chrome during any CSS animations

Tags: css, css-animations

See the picture below.  The image on the left is during "resting state", the image on the right is during a CSS3 animation on a different element on the page (the animation is also on an SVG icon though).

The animation is simple:

```
element {
    -webkit-transform  : scale( .8 );
    -webkit-transition : all .2s;
}

element:hover {
    -webkit-transform  : scale( 1 );
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  Ideally how to make the icons "always sharp", but "always blurry" would work as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
element {
    -webkit-transform  : scale(.8) translatez(0);
    -webkit-transition : all .2s;
}

element:hover {
    -webkit-transform  : scale(1) translatez(0);
}
```